# Firebase: Cloud function changing data in firestore - Permission denied on resource project [X:YYYYYYYYYY:web:KKKKKKKKKKKK]

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to add data to my firestore collection via firebase cloud functions. However, when executing the function the following error appears.

My cloud function code is:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();
const Firestore = require("@google-cloud/firestore");
const PROJECTID = "[...]";

const firestore = new Firestore({
  projectId: PROJECTID,
  timestampsInSnapshots: true,
});
exports.createNewChat = functions.region("europe-west1")
    .https.onRequest((request, response) => {
      console.log("!!!!!!");
      console.log("THe BodY: " + request);
      console.log("THe BodY: " + request.rawBody);
      console.log("THe BodY: " + request.body);
      try {
        const groupName = request.body.groupName;
        const members: string[] = request.body.members;
        firestore.collection("chats").add({
          groupName: groupName,
          members: members,
          lastMessage: new Date(),
          messages: [],
        }).then((doc: any) => {
          const chatId = doc.id;
          members.forEach((member) => {
            firestore.collection("myChats/" + member).add({
              chatKey: chatId,
            });
          });
          return response.status(200).send(doc);
        });
      } catch (e) {
        functions.logger.log("catch clause " + e);
        response.status(500).send(e);
      }
    });
```

My postman request looks like this:

- Header: Content-Type -> application/json
- Body (raw, json):

  {
  "groupName": "someGroupName",
  "members": [
  "123321aklslasl"
  ]
  }

The exception which is thrown is:

> !  Google API requested!
>
> - URL: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
> - Be careful, this may be a production service.
>   (node:23224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied on resource project [...].
>   at Object.callErrorFromStatus (E:\Workspaces\cloudFunctions\functions\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:31:26)
>   at Object.onReceiveStatus (E:\Workspaces\cloudFunctions\functions\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:179:52)
>   at Object.onReceiveStatus (E:\Workspaces\cloudFunctions\functions\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:336:141)
>   at Object.onReceiveStatus (E:\Workspaces\cloudFunctions\functions\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:299:181)
>   at E:\Workspaces\cloudFunctions\functions\node_modules@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:145:78
>   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
>   Caused by: Error
>   at WriteBatch.commit (E:\Workspaces\cloudFunctions\functions\node_modules@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\write-batch.js:414:23)
>   at DocumentReference.create (E:\Workspaces\cloudFunctions\functions\node_modules@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:291:14)
>   at CollectionReference.add (E:\Workspaces\cloudFunctions\functions\node_modules@google-cloud\firestore\build\src\reference.js:1967:28)
>   at E:\Workspaces\cloudFunctions\functions\lib\index.js:39:39
>   at C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:560:16
>   at runFunction (C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:533:15)
>   at runHTTPS (C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:559:11)
>   at handler (C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:479:23)
>   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>   at next (C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>   (node:23224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). T
>   o terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
>   (node:23224) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Can you show the entire content of your `index.js` file?

Comment: Sure @RenaudTarnec
 I just added the missing lines to the question.